# Graph API - Daemon app with User Consent

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal, office365api, azure-ad-msal

We want to create an  API App(Main purpose is to contact our organizations Office 365 Graph endpoint and send email) in Azure.. however our frontend website doesn't use Azure AD for the user authentication.. however we want our backend APi to be able send email in one of the following ways
1) send email as any user
2) send email on behalf of a service account

we are trying to explore the possible options and based on the investigation done so far, this(option 1) can be done using admin_consent - Can someone help with the steps we need to follow to create such app and deploy.

additionally is there a way to create an API app without login screen being prompted during the execution of the API - while using user_consent?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

In order for an app/daemon to send email as any user, it must have the *send mail as any user app permission*.

Give that permission on the Microsoft Graph API to the app, then grant the permission by clicking the Grant Permissions button in the portal, or by going through the admin consent flow.

Your API can then authenticate with its client credentials and get an access token to send email.

The bad side of this approach should be obvious, the app gets rights to send emails as *anyone* in your org.

**Option 2**

You could alternatively create an account for the API, and then use the Resource Owner Password grant flow to authenticate. You would then give the delegated permission for sending email as the signed in user.

The bad side of this is the flow for authenticating. If the account's password expires, there is no way for you to reset it from there, you would have to intervene to fix the problem.

**Consent**

You cannot go through consent without the browser UI.

Comment: Thankyou @juunas, looks like **option #2** is not a choice in my case, resource owner password grant flow is only working when my dev machine is connected to my companies VPN, hence if I host my api in azure this will not work without a virtual network being established..

**Option #1** is also ruled out based on my discussion with our security team, who owns the azure active directory ownership of our organization.

Is this possible?
admin allows the app to send mail as a single user(service acc) in organization
My app will be able to use client credentials and send email from that acc

Comment: If you are asking for app-only client_credentials permission that is limited to "work with" certain accounts, we don't have this today AFAIK, although it *might* be possible if Exchange online allows you to restrict what your app API is allowed to do.  Anyway, if this is what you are looking for, please file an ask on Uservoice https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis

Comment: Yes @DanKershaw-MSFT, I am trying to do exactly the same.. i captured my scenario and idea in following

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19188046-app-only-client-credentials-permission-for-consent

Comment: For people of the future, if your AD is federated and you are running on Windows you can use Integrated Windows Authentication. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication